# Program crashing with embedded Python/C++ code across DLL boundary in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, boost-python

Sorry for the long post. I've searched around quite a bit and couldn't find an answer for this so here it goes:

I am working developing a Python extension library using C++ (BoostPython). For testing, we have a Python-based test harness but I also want to add a separate C++ executable (eg. using BoostUnitTest or similar) to add further testing of the library including testing of the functionality that is not directly exposed to Python.

I am currently running this in Linux without problems. I am building the library and this then is dynamically linked to an executable that uses BoostUnitTest. Everything compiles and runs as expected.
In Windows though, I'm having problems. I think it might a problem with the registering of the C++->Python type converters across DLL boundaries.
To show the problem I have the following example:
In my library I have defined:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;
namespace bn = boost::numpy;

class DLL_API DummyClass
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<DummyClass> Create()
    { 
        return std::make_shared<DummyClass>();
    }
    static void RegisterPythonBindings();
};
void DummyClass::RegisterPythonBindings()
{
    bp::class_<DummyClass>("DummyClass", bp::init<>())
        ;

    bp::register_ptr_to_python< std::shared_ptr<DummyClass> >();
}
```

where DLL_API is the usual _declspec(…) for Windows. The idea is that this dummy class would be exported as part of a bigger Python module with

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module)
{
    DummyClass::RegisterPythonBindings();
}
```

From within the executable linking to the library I have (omitting includes, etc):

```
void main()
{   
    Py_Initialize();
    DummyClass::RegisterPythonBindings();
    auto myDummy = DummyClass::Create();
    auto dummyObj = bp::object( myDummy );
}
```

The last line where I wrap myDummy within a boost::python::object crashes with an unhandled exception in Windows. The exception is being thrown from Python (throw_error_already_set). I believe (but could be wrong) that it is not finding an appropriate converter of the C++ type to Python, even though I made the call to register the bindings.

```
KernelBase.dll!000007fefd91a06d()
msvcr110.dll!000007fef7bde92c()
TestFromMain.exe!boost::python::throw_error_already_set(void)
TestFromMain.exe!boost::python::converter::registration::to_python(void const volatile *)
TestFromMain.exe!boost::python::converter::detail::arg_to_python_base::arg_to_python_base(void const volatile *,struct boost::python::converter::registration const &)
TestFromMain.exe!main() Line 66
TestFromMain.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()
kernel32.dll!0000000077a259cd()
ntdll.dll!0000000077b5a561()
```

As a test, I copied the exact same code defining the DummyClass all inside the executable just before the main function, instead of linking to the dll, and this works as expected.

Is my model of compiling as a DLL using embedded python in both sides of the boundary even possible in Windows (this is only used for a testing harness so I’d always use the exact same toolchain all over).

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ever reads this again, the solution in Windows was to compile Boost as dynamic libraries and link everything dynamically. We had to change the structure of our code a bit, but it now works.

There is a (small) reference in the Boost documentation stating that in Windows the dynamic lib version of Boost has one common register of types used for conversion between Python/C+. The doc doesn't mention not having a common register for the static lib version (but I now know it doesn't work).